# Usage of Multiple Egress IPs in Google Cloud NAT Setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nat, gke-networking

I have configured a Google Cloud NAT setup with two egress IPs and running a GKE private cluster.
One of the egress IPs is functioning correctly, but I'm unsure about the usage or purpose of the second egress IP. How can I determine which traffic is routed through the second egress IP and whether it's being utilized effectively? Are there any specific monitoring tools or techniques I can use to analyze the usage of each egress IP in my Cloud NAT setup?

Also I notice when I exec into any pod and curl http://ipecho.net/plain then it return 1 cloud nat egress IP
but what is the use of cloud nat 2nd IP?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By default, NAT works for all primary and secondary IP ranges for all subnets in the region for the given VPC network. May be there is a restriction about use of only primary or only secondary subnet ranges that can use NAT.You can check the [official document](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/set-up-manage-network-address-translation#specify_subnet_ranges_for_nat) for more information.